# Looking up words easily in the dictionary

Tags: applications, system-apps, default-applications, paid-apps

Would it be possible for an entry to be installed on the menu that shows up when I highlight a word, so that I can look up the word on a dictionary, for example from an installed app such as Merriam-Webster dictionary. The app could show the definition inside a bubble.

If course, the installed app would have to support this, and install the behavior onto the operating system UI.

How can I achieve the behavior I'm looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: This dictionary adds an entry in the context menu to directly search a word when highlighted. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vaibhav.dictionary&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Denglish+dictionary+android&pcampaignid=APPU_1_Wj5wXMCJFYb4rQGIpJXwDQ

Comment: There are many as you can see [here](https://appgoli.com/top-5-best-pop-dictionary-apps-android/). Last one on the list I used for a while and is good. But none of them can let you select a dictionary of your choice - they have their own inbuilt dictionary